# android - auto-login with facebook sdk

Tags: android

I want to use the facebook sdk and be able to automatically login after the app has already logged in once.

Currently from what I can gather if you use the facebook api and you have the facebook app installed and you have signed in with the facebook app then you don't have to login and you will be automatically logged in.

But if you don't have the facebook app then this automatic login will not happen. -----------I want to handle this case and be still able to automatically log in after the user has logged in with my app once.-------------. From my understanding the facebook sdk requires you to login if the facebook app is not there.

Also if the user has logged in once with my app, I will have the access token then as long as the access token has not expired then you don't need to log in again. But if the access token expires then you have to log in again.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The functionality you're describing is called single sign on.  Facebook has an entire article dedicated to describing how it works and how to implement it.  Enjoy:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/android_sso/